# how to set query level time out in hibernate 3 + oracle using java

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate3

I want to stop a long running query in Oracle + Hibernate 3 + Java.

I have tried setting the timeout using the code snippets below, without success.

1.

```
query = session.createQuery("from table");
query.setTimeout(1000);
list = query.list();
```

2.

```
Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
tx.setTimeout(1000);
tx.begin(); 
query = session.createQuery("from table");
list = query.list();
```

Could anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How to kill or cancel long running query within some configured time in oracle 11g and Hibernate 3 using java

Answer (score 0):

You could try option listed here [Hibernate: set default query timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101455/hibernate-set-default-query-timeout)

Also if you host a webservice , under which you run this Db query, and wish to timeout the webservice if response is not returned in x seconds, then you can set connection timeout for the webservice (even on server side). Note: That would not kill the oracle process running the query though. 
[Spring ws timeout on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029505/spring-ws-timeout-on-server-side)

Comment: its not working.
How to kill or cancel long running query from oracle 11g and Hibernate 3 using java...